# Finding greatest difference between elements of two lists

Tags: java, list

My code is:

```
int diff = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i<listOne.size(); i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j<listTwo.size(); j++)
    {
      if (listOne.get(i)-listTwo.get(j)>diff)
        diff = listOne.get(i)-listTwo.get(j);
      if (listTwo.get(j)-listOne.get(i)>diff)
        diff = listTwo.get(j)-listOne.get(i);
    }
  }
  return diff;
```

The task is to find the greatest difference between any two numbers in two inputted lists (the difference must be between a number from list one and a number from list two).

I cannot tell what is wrong with my code.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Sorting two lists and getting the difference between maximum and minimum from each list may work for your need, isn't it?

Comment: Please consider provide us a output example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Downvoted for not explaining the actual issue you are having. What exactly is unclear? What exactly do you have trouble with? What is your reasoning behind this code, explain it and we can check it against the code and explain what went wrong.

Comment: @TharinduSathischandra No need for sorting (_O(n log n)_), just get the min/max values (_O(n)_), otherwise **great answer**. Too bad you can't make it an answer, now that question has been closed, because I would up-vote it.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing [Math.abs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)) executed on the diff. Difference is an absolute value, so difference between 5 to 7 and 7 to 5 is same - `2`.

```
int diff = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<listOne.size(); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j<listTwo.size(); j++) {
    int elementDiff = Math.abs(listOne.get(i)-listTwo.get(j)); 
    if (elementDiff>diff) {
      diff = elementDiff;
  }
 }
}
return diff;
```

So both below lines will produce same results:

```
int elementDiff = Math.abs(listOne.get(i)-listTwo.get(j));
int elementDiff = Math.abs(listTwo.get(i)-listOne.get(j));
```